# How can I get auto-complete content in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any option that I can use to type faster without spelling mistakes? 
I have already searched menus of `eclipse` but couldn't find.

Comment: Do you mean CTRL + space?

Comment: [Might be helpful.](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/eclipse.html)

Comment: I have updated your title by replacing 'I' with 'i' and  removed small grammatical mistake from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTRL + Space will show you a list of proposals.

If this is not enough, you can go to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist. You'll be able to play around with the settings there.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl-space key to trigger an auto-complete

Answer (score 0):

Type few alphabets e.g `st` and then press `Ctrl+space` together it will show options which start with `st`:

[image]

Then select one which you need, this way you can type faster and without making any syntactically incorrect name. Though it does not guarantee spelling mistake as such. I prefer IntelliJ over Eclipse.